# More Pager not showing on Front page

Tags: 7, paging

I'm not sure what I've done wrong, but I just noticed that the front page of my site isn't showing the pager at the bottom so that visitors can get to older posts.

http://www.theresatutors.com/

I don't remember changing anything to hide this anywhere. What would cause this? Where can I look to turn it back on?

I've been searching trying to find a solution, but all of the pages that show up in my searches are people trying to hide the pager, not show the pager. :/

As far as I can tell I'm not overriding the mainpage in anyway or using Pages or anything like that. Just the standard Drupal homepage with standard Drupal blocks.

My theme settings for Bartik are set to allow 10 posts per page. I have 16 posts which are Published and Promoted to Front Page.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: go to admin/config/system/site-information and set the limit of posts on front page. The pager should show up only if the number of posts will exceed the limit

Comment: That value is set to 10 and I have 16 posts which are Published and Promoted to the Front Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

I had a View in the Featured section which showed an image gallery. The Views configuration had a pager on that data and so it was overriding the main pager on the page. I changed the Pager config on the View to "Display All Items" and the main pager is showing now.